# kafka connector converter retrieves schema by subject name

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

If the schema name does not follow the pattern of topicNameStrategy, i.e. -value
The connector will throw an exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro value schema version for id 11025
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Subject not found. io.confluent.rest.exceptions.RestNotFoundException: Subject not found.
io.confluent.rest.exceptions.RestNotFoundException: Subject not found.
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.exceptions.Errors.subjectNotFoundException(Errors.java:51)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.resources.SubjectsResource.lookUpSchemaUnderSubject(SubjectsResource.java:93)
```

Looking into schema registry code of lookUpSchemaUnderSubject in schema-registry SubjectsResource.java, it indicates that client attempts to lookup schema by subject and subjectName is constructed by topicNameStrategy

Why not just by ID as global ID is indeed unique per schema per version?
Or at least fall back to look up by ID only if subject cannot be found?

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason - The global ID has no concept of compatibility across records. That's only something defined at the scope of the subject versions.

As a workaround, you can simply pull the global ID listed in the error, then post that to the registry as the subject you need, and restart the connector.

Otherwise, if the data is already bytes with an ID that exists in the registry, don't use any converter except for ByteArrayConverter. Otherwise, if you used AvroConverter, for example, you'd end up with a schema type of `bytes`, and not your real record.

Comment: each record has its schema id wired as the first 5 bytes. this is the schema used to serialize the record I'd assume de-serialize the message with same schema ID would be the right way to do because schema ID is unique. Any changes in schema would result  a different schema ID.   schemaId is the only reliable way to guarantee compatibility as far as I can understand

Comment: I've implement a quick fix to scan all messages under a topic, extract schemaID from message and try to create <topic-name>-value subject under that ID if  not exists. This works but I'd consider it as a work around, not official solution as consuming all messages in a topic would be time and resource consuming.

Comment: Avro needs both the reader and writer schema. It cannot use only the ID written by the producer. The subject lookup finds the reader schema for the writer schema ID